# spring boot security static resources

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf, wro4j

I write app in Spring Boot, Spring Security with Thymeleaf and I try to get access my static resource file...

This is my project structure...

```
    .
    ├── mvnw
    ├── mvnw.cmd
    ├── nb-configuration.xml
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   ├── java
    │   │   │   └── com
    │   │   ├── resources
    │   │   │   ├── application.properties
    │   │   │   ├── static
    |   |   |   |    |---------------------------------this is image.jpg
    │   │   │   ├── templates
    │   │   │   └── ValidationMessages.properties
    │   │   └── wro
    │   │       ├── css
    │   │       ├── fonts
    │   │       ├── js
    │   │       ├── scss
    │   │       ├── wro.properties
    │   │       └── wro.xml
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── com
```

I have HTML file in templates/index.html where i try use tag

```
     <img src="/praca.jpg" alt="sd"/>
```

Why I always get 404 error ? Where I do something wrong ??

My general init class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(InzynierkaApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My security class:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserAuthenticationDetails userAuthenticationDetails;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userAuthenticationDetails);
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userAuthenticationDetails);
            authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authenticationProvider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/","/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, does the entire page return a 404 or just the image asset?

Comment: 404 return just a image asset. Other content load successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In your template you need to use the thymeleaf format to add automatically the context by yourself. Use this:

```
<img th:src="@{/praca.jpg}" alt="sd"/>
```

*/praca.jpg*

should be the full path to the image from the static or public folder

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the problem was with spring security, so anyone having this issue can try adding the folders where their static files are to the list of URLs that do not require authentication
E.g `antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do static resources in Spring Boot, in your `WebConfig` class or the class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, add this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Then, in `resources` create an `static` folder where you put all the static files or folders like `resources/css`, `resources/js`, etc

From your view you can access it like this for example:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/skin-black.css">
```

If you are using Spring Security make sure you add the `antMatchers`

```
.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
```